# Select radio button from a tr onclick

Tags: jquery

Here's my tr which is inside a form:

```
        <tr id="mlevel" class="__tr_class__" onclick="needFunction()">
            <td class="checkbox"><input type="radio" name="membership" id="__ID__" value="__ID__" /></td>
            <td class="icon"><img src="__Icon__" width="60" height="60"/></td>
            <td class="name"><h2>__Name__</h2></td>
            <td class="price"><h4>__Price__ for __Days__ Days</h4></td> 
            <td class="auto"><h4>__Auto__</h4></td>
            <td class="auto"><h4>__Active__</h4></td>
        </tr>
```

When I click on the tr I want the Radio Input to be selected. I would like to use jquery or something simple.  Just not sure which way to go. Does anyone know of a simple function to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't really need a function, the following should work:

```
$('tr').click(
    function() {
        $('input[type=radio]',this).attr('checked','checked');
    }
);
```

---

**Edited** in response to @whatshakin's question:

> that works perfectly. Can you explain: $('input[type=radio]',this)

This looks for an element that matches the 'input[type=radio]' using a CSS3 style attribute selector (looking for `input` elements of `type="radio"`) *within* the context of `this` (`this` being the current object, in this instance the `tr`).

A slightly more authoritative description/explanation of how this works is at [api.jquery.com/jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

---

**Edited** because it was irritating me that the radio couldn't be un-checked, the following corrects that:

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('tr').toggle(
      function(){
        $('input:radio', this).attr('checked',true);
      },
      function() {
        $('input:radio', this).attr('checked',false);
      }
      );
  }
  );
```

With thanks @Thomas (in comments) for pointing out the erroneous assumption I made in the previous code, that while `$(this).attr('checked','checked')` evaluates to true, obviously `''` wouldn't evaluate to false. Hopefully this approach rectifies that earlier naïveté and silliness.

Also: demo located at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/itotu3)

---

**Edited** the above code (the one using `toggle()`) in response to @Tim Büthe's comment:

> Why don't you use the ":radio" pseudo selector?

A pseudo-selector that I *didn't even know about* until I read his comment, and then visited the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/).

Comment: that works perfectly.  Can you explain: $('input[type=radio]',this)

Comment: In jQuery, you set the attributes 'checked' and 'selected' with value true/false. In this case the value 'checked' will evaluate to true, but it's misleading, because '' will not evaluate to false.

Comment: Sorry I had to edit that, you answered too soon: $('input[type=radio]',this)

Comment: @Thomas, thanks. I'd sort-of half-kinda-realised that but not done anything about it. Since rectified, if you'd be willing to double-check/proof-read for me?

Comment: Your code has the same problem as mine, the toggle doesn't work if you click directly on the radio button (that'll only check it, but not uncheck it).

Comment: @Peter, well no. But that's not expected behaviour for a radio-button, because that's the native browser action (You can click to de-select a checkbox, but the only way to de-select a radio button is to click on *another* radio-button with the same `name`, or use a `form` reset button).

Comment: @David - The drawback to your solution (`.toggle()`) vs mine (use checked state) is that if you have multiple radio buttons, you have to click on a rows twice if you alternately click on the rows: http://jsfiddle.net/ESNAQ/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/LVQS4/ (only 1 click required even with multiple alternate clicks)

Comment: Why don't you use the ":radio" pseudo selector?

Comment: @Tim, honestly? Because I didn't know it existed until now =( ...so, thanks! =D

Comment: @Peter, that's true. +1 to you =)

Comment: how would you use the pseudo selector?

Comment: If you look at the second example-code, you'll see I already edited it to use the pseudo-selector. Here's the [jQuery reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/#post-639)

Comment: this is not working on multiple radio button with same name, but changing the `attr` to `prop` made it working.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a neat toggle that works without inline Javascript (and **[with multiple radio buttons](http://jsfiddle.net/LVQS4/)**):

### The Code:

```
$(function() { // <== Doc ready

    $('tr').click(function(event) {  

        if(event.target.type != "radio") {

            var that = $(this).find('input:radio');
            that.attr('checked', !that.is(':checked'));

        }
    });
});
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/KC4DK/)**

### The Breakdown:

1. Create a **[`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)** handler for all `tr` elements with `$(tr).click()`
2. In the handler assign a variable to the radio button within the tr using `$(this).find('input:radio')`. This looks through all the descendants of `this` (the `tr` clicked) and finds the radio buttons. The **[jQuery context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)** uses **[`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)** in its implementation, so the previous is synonymous with `$('input:radio', this)`
3. Set the `checked` attribute of the radio button to the opposite of what it is. Things can be checked or unchecked with `true` or `false`, and `.is(':checked)` returns `true` or `false`. `!that.is(':checked')` simply is the opposite of the currently checked state. Note that we don't want to fire this action if the user clicks directly on the radio button, since that'd cancel the native effect of the check, so we use `if (event.target.type != "radio")`.

Comment: Why don't you use the ":radio" pseudo selector?

Comment: @Tim - Good idea. Edited to `input:radio` (simply `:radio` is slower) ==> http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/

Comment: Yes, I meant "input:radio" instead of "input[type=radio]". It's simple and better readable and does the same underneath. However, if you care about performance of this selector, you should add the context "this" like @David Thomas has done, especially if it is a really big document.

Comment: @Tim - What do you mean "add the context `this`"? I explain in point #2 how `$(this).find('input:radio');` is synonymous with `$('input:radio', this)`. I believe `find()` is probably a little faster, since internally the context is an implementation of `find()`. ---- At any rate, I create the `that` variable and only use `$(this)` once precisely for performance.

Comment: @Peter: yes, you are right. You use this, I overread that fact. Then I will say, if you already in a small context like the given. Where you have only a tr-element containing two or three children, performance dosen't matter. You should go for readability in that case.

Comment: and with overread I mean "i didn't saw it, did not read your answer carefully enough. Man, I should head over to http://english.stackexchange.com/ and find out if "overread" is a real word :-)

Comment: @Tim - I use `that` for readability, since without defining `that` the following line would be much longer, since `that` is used twice in the line after its definition. So the use of `that` both improves performance and readability. ---- I think it's "misread" ;)

Comment: It's a rare occurrence in the English language when use of the words `this` and `that` aids understanding... =)